# how to configure oracle job to run at every minute of 00 second

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, scheduler

I want to create a job in oracle which runs for every minute at 00 second like 01:00 (MI:SS), 02:00 and 03:00 ...

I have created a job like as shown below

```
begin
  sys.dbms_job.submit(job => :job,
                      what => 'RECONUAT.USP_LOCK_APP_AFTER_EODTIME;',
                      next_date => to_date('10-05-2019 17:17:32', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
                      interval => 'SYSDATE+1/1440'); 
  commit; 
end; 
/
```

It is also running for every minute but seconds are varying like 01:00, 02:16, 03:32 ...

My requirement is to run job for every minute of 00 second.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

`sys.dbms_job.submit` is deprecated, prefer using `sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job` as

```
declare
    v_job_name varchar2(32) := 'JB_LOCK_APP_AFTER_EODTIME';
begin  
    sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job(
        job_name => v_job_name,
        job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
        job_action => 'RECONUAT.USP_LOCK_APP_AFTER_EODTIME', 
        start_date => to_date('10-05-2019 15:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
        repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=1;BYSECOND=0;', 
        auto_drop => false,
        comments => 'Populates our table every minute');

    dbms_scheduler.enable(v_job_name);    
end;
```

a starting time might be chosen before the current time. Adding `BYSECOND=0` to `repeat_interval` parameter might do the trick about exact minute.